# Does the CancellationTokenSource returned by CreateLinkedTokenSource needs disposing

Tags: c#, cancellationtokensource

If I use the [`CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.createlinkedtokensource?view=netcore-3.1) to link two `CancellationToken` instances together does the returned `CancellationTokenSource` needs to be disposed after I no longer need it? Let's say I have the following method:

```cs
public async Task DoStuffAsync(CancellationToken token1, CancellationToken token2)
{
    var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(token1, token2);

    await DoOtherStuffAsync(cts.Token);
}
```

Will this lead to a memory leak under the assumption that the original `CancellationTokenSource` instances are properly disposed?

Comment: You can easily find it in the docs: [How to: Listen for Multiple Cancellation Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/how-to-listen-for-multiple-cancellation-requests?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, all `CancellationTokenSource`s need to be disposed. I'm not aware of any exception for linked CTSs.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap the `CancellationTokenSource` in a `using` statement, they are allocating some additional resources under the hood, for example a system timer

Answer (score -1):

As a rule, for any `IDisposable` object that you create, or is created for you by a library, is it your responsibility to ensure that `.Dispose()` is called. Always.

It is a common misconception that the Garbage Collector will call `.Dispose()` for you.

**It does not.**

However, if an object has a finalizer AND that finalizer calls `.Dispose()` then the Garbage Collector will eventually trigger a call to `.Dispose()`. Eventually. Maybe.

Remember that there is no guarantee that the GC will ever call the finalizer.

**You must explicitly check that the object has a finalizer and that it calls `.Dispose()` for you to know that there is a good likelihood that the GC will call `.Dispose()`.**

So, that all said. The **only safe thing to do is to explicitly call `.Dispose()` always.** For every `IDisposable` instance. Every single time.

Always.

I hope I've made my point.